# Clarifications on how scoped variables behave in the context of a Javascript closure

Tags: javascript, closures

#### Context

I have this code

```js
var a = 10;
 
// function "outer" created a closure of the global scope
// the moment it was defined
function outer() {
    // variable a is available in this scope (execution context)
    const b = 10;
 
    // function "inner" created a closure of the global scope
    // and outer function's scope the moment it was defined.
    // When it's executed it can use this closure as part of
    // its own scope
    function inner() {
        // variables a and b are available in this scope
        const c = 20;
        console.log(a + b + c);
    }
 
    return inner;
}
```

The closure for `inner` has these scopes:

- Local scope
- Outer function's scope
- Global scope

Let's execute `outer` and then execute the return value, which is `inner` :

```js
const inner = outer();
inner() // prints 40
```

Now here is where I am confused. I *always* thought that the `inner` function gets a "snapshot" of variables `a` and `b` as they existed the moment `inner` was defined.

So, *I thought* that after `const inner = outer();`, then **every** execution of `inner` would **always** return `40`.

However I came to find out (while making a demonstration nonetheless) that this is not what happens

```js
const inner = outer();
a = 100;
inner() // prints 130 while I expected for inner to be "locked" to 40
```

#### Question

I would like someone to clarify/correct my mental model of how closures work in js.

More specifically, I expected that the moment a function is defined, it gets a hold of all the outer scopes defined up to that moment and `var` (or `const` or `let`) values stay "locked" to the values they had the moment the function (in this case function `inner`) was defined.

However, I just showcased that altering the value of one of the variables referenced inside `inner` actually changes its return value.

So, **values are evaluated "live" when the `inner` function gets executed instead of being a snapshot of what they were the moment `inner` was defined?**

Comment: Java behaves as you describe (well, before arrow functions), but not JavaScript. The closure is a live place where those variables "live", and they can be changed.

Comment: A closure remembers the connection between the variable and a location where its value is stored. That location can be updated, which is what happens when you reassign the variable.

Comment: Your mental model should consider references rather than variables. That should clear things up.

Comment: [This "better programing" article](https://medium.com/better-programming/execution-context-lexical-environment-and-closures-in-javascript-b57c979341a5) will probably tell you more than you ever wanted to know about this issue.

Comment: @RandyCasburn of course, almost everything works by reference in JS, it makes total sense in hindsight. Thanks.